# titlesec - runin title with default dot spacing

Tags: spacing, titlesec

I'm trying to add a dot at the end of the default `\paragraph`, but want its spacing to be consistent with the usual "post-dot spacing" (and don't want to just use `\frenchspacing`). The `\wordsep` command that [`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) provides unfortunately only adds the normal whitespace, not the "post-dot space". I tried adding regular whitespaces in some of the arguments of the `\titleformat` command (e.g. after the dot, including using `\titlesec`'s `explicit` option), but it seems to be ignored / gobbled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[.]
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{\wordsep}
\begin{document}
    \paragraph{Paragraph} \vrule\\
    \textbf{Paragraph.} \vrule
\end{document}
```

[image: output (cropped)]

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to reverse-engineer a bit.

The `titlesec` package defines `\wordsep` as

```
\newcommand\wordsep{\fontdimen\tw@\font \@plus
  \fontdimen\thr@@\font \@minus \fontdimen4\font}
```

`\fontdimen\thr@@\font` and such are essentially equivalent to `\fontdimen3\font` and such (TeXBook p. 345), which are themselves explained in TeXBook p. 433, TeX by Topic p. 31, as well as in [How does TeX know how to space different typefaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30746/170958).

Now, to find out how TeX changes the spacing after dots specifically, TeXBook p. 351 proves useful, where `\nonfrenchspacing` is defined:

```
\def\nonfrenchspacing{\sfcode‘\.=3000 \sfcode‘\?=3000 \sfcode‘\!=3000
  \sfcode‘\:=2000 \sfcode‘\;=1500 \sfcode‘\,=1250 }
```

TeX by Topic p. 155 explains that `\sfcode` sets `\spacefactor` for a specific character. Setting `\spacefactor` to 3000 here then has three consequences (on the glue following a sentence-ending period):

- Stretchability is multiplied by 3000/1000
- Schrinkability is multiplied by 1000/3000
- Because 3000 is greater or equal to 2000, the "extra space" `\fontdimen7\font` is added

Hence, I'd expect the following to do the trick:

```
\newcommand\postdotsep{\dimexpr\fontdimen\thr@@\font+\fontdimen7\font \@plus
  \dimexpr3\fontdimen\thr@@\font \@minus \dimexpr\fontdimen4\font/3}
```

And indeed, this works!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\postdotsep{\dimexpr\fontdimen\tw@\font+\fontdimen7\font\@plus
  \dimexpr3\fontdimen\thr@@\font \@minus \dimexpr\fontdimen4\font/3}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[.]
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{\postdotsep}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \paragraph{Paragraph} \vrule\\
    \textbf{Paragraph.} \vrule
\end{document}
```